# Ruby ternary in a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, erb

My basic question is how can I turn this to one line of code using a ternary?

```
 <% if tip_off %>
  <%= link_to "Dead Man's Snitch", [:homepage], class: "topbar-brand-tip-off", rel: "home" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Dead Man's Snitch", [:homepage], class: "topbar-brand", rel: "home" %>
<% end %>
```

All I'm doing is changing the class name if a particular condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more readable in two lines I think

```
<% link_class = tip_off ? "topbar-brand-tip-off" : "topbar-brand" %>
<%= link_to "Dead Man's Snitch", [:homepage], class: link_class, rel: "home" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

By interpolating into the class value:

```
<%= link_to "Dead Man's Snitch", [:homepage], class: "topbar-brand#{tip_off ? '-tip-off': ''}", rel: "home" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it outside the link_to:

```
<% css_class = tip_off ? "topbar-brand-tip-off" : "topbar-brand" %>
<%= link_to "Dead Man's Snitch", [:homepage], class: css_class, rel: "home" %>
```

Or you can do it with interpolation

```
<%= link_to "Dead Man's Snitch", [:homepage], class: "topbar-brand#{'-tip-off' if tip-off}", rel: "home" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use rails built in `link_to_if`

```
 link_to_if(tip_off, "Dead Man's Snitch", { [ACTION_OPTIONS] }, class: "topbar-brand-tip-off") do
    link_to("Dead Man's Snitch", { [ACTION_OPTIONS] }, class: "topbar-brand") 
 end
```

docs: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if